# How to use public method updatePosition of react-virtualized?

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

The docs: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/WindowScroller.md#updateposition

But I checkout the source: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/WindowScroller/WindowScroller.js

It's not a public method, so how can I use this method to update scroll position when other element size changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I checkout the source...It's not a public method

It's [right here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/838b5b541116d1be3cf66cfb6b38a76bfe6c7759/source/WindowScroller/WindowScroller.js#L79-L99) and it has [some unit tests too](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/WindowScroller/WindowScroller.jest.js#L281-L355).

To use it you'll need to set a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to `WindowScroller`. Here's a minimal example of what I mean:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WindowScroller
        ref={this._setRef}
        {...otherProps}
      />
    );
  }

  _setRef = ref => {
    this.windowScrollerRef = ref;
  }

  someOtherMethod() {
    // Assuming you've mounted, you can access public methods like:
    this.windowScrollerRef.updatePosition();
  }
}
```