# Couldn't load resource Error : net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, fetch-api

I'm using react JS for front end and .NET API for backend, I'm trying to fetch data from API. I enabled CORS (I added some configuration in startup file) and it's all fine normally.

In react js, I want to fetch data using my API so this is my code to show a list of data:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { List, Avatar, Button, Spin } from "antd";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import reqwest from "reqwest";

const fakeDataUrl =
  "http://localhost:51492/api/experience/";

class LoadMoreList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    loadingMore: false,
    showLoadingMore: true,
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData(res => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        data: res.results
      });
    });
  }

  getData = callback => {
    reqwest({
      url: fakeDataUrl,
      type: "json",
      method: "get",
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: res => {
        callback(res);
      }
    });
  };

  onLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState({
      loadingMore: true
    });
    this.getData(res => {
      const data = this.state.data.concat(res.results);
      this.setState(
        {
          data,
          loadingMore: false
        },
        () => {
          // Resetting window's offsetTop so as to display react-virtualized demo underfloor.
          // In real scene, you can using public method of react-virtualized:
          // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700726/how-to-use-public-method-updateposition-of-react-virtualized
          window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
        }
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, loadingMore, showLoadingMore, data } = this.state;
    const loadMore = showLoadingMore ? (
      <div
        style={{
          textAlign: "center",
          marginTop: 12,
          height: 32,
          lineHeight: "32px"
        }}
      >
        {loadingMore && <Spin />}
        {!loadingMore && (
          <Button onClick={this.onLoadMore}>loading more</Button>
        )}
      </div>
    ) : null;
    return (
      <List
        style={{
          width: "50%",
          left: "25%"
        }}
        className="demo-loadmore-list"
        loading={loading}
        itemLayout="horizontal"
        loadMore={loadMore}
        dataSource={data}
        renderItem={item => (
          <List.Item
            actions={[
              <Button type="primary" icon="user-add">
                suivre
              </Button>,
              <a>Message</a>
            ]}
          >
            <List.Item.Meta
              avatar={
                <a>
                  <Avatar src="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png" />{" "}
                </a>
              }
              title={<a href="https://ant.design">{item.titre}</a>}
             />
          </List.Item>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

LoadMoreList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles()(LoadMoreList);
```

This code will show a list of experiences and it allows us to load more data clicking on LoadMore,
but what I get when I start the project:

[image]

and in DevTools I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I looked in Google for many solutions but none helped me.

Comment: some adblock maybe?

Comment: @aviram83 i unsintalled adblock , the error disappeared but it shows no data

Comment: can you see a request in the network tab (in DevTools)? also consider to add [CodePane](https://codepen.io/pen)

Comment: now it  shows in dev tools :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
i didn't understand  where to add codepen.io/pen/](CodePane)

Comment: maybe it's authentication issue on local service? about CodePane, can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: after deleting adblock , i decided to work with axios instead of reqwest, and now it works perfectly , thank u @aviram83